# Trying to press keys and shortcuts in a hidden CMD window

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I am trying to create a script that will use the `copy con` to write a file

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
CurrentUser = objNetwork.UserName

Set Wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Wshell.Run "%COMSPEC% cd C:\Users\" & CurrentUser & _
  "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup & copy con master.vbs & x = 1 & x=2^Z", 0, True
```

The problem here is that while using `^Z` does simulate the output of <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, CMD doesn't treat them the same.

As you can see, I wanted the console window to be hidden, so using something like `SendKeys` won't work here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a typo `CurrentUser` <> `CurrnetUser`. Otherwise good luck. I don't think the copy con CTRL+Z idea will lead you anywhere useful.

Comment: hmm... I thought that this might be the answer - is PowerShell any better?

Comment: VBScript doesn't need `COPY CON` for writing files. Not even batch needs `COPY CON` for writing files. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: I know I can use File I/O to do this, but I need to do it using CMD or Powershell. I can't disclose exactly why but if I was allowed to by the creative constraints I gave myself, I would.

Comment: `copy con` opens and reads from the console input buffer.  The remaining `& x = 1 & x=2^Z` in the command line is wrong. It's not going to be written into master.vbs. It seems to me that you want something like this: `Wshell.Run "%ComSpec% /c ""cd /d %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup && ((echo x=1 & echo x=2) >master.vbs)""", 0, True`.

Comment: Yep, that worked; but can you explain to me why? What command is being executed in cmd?

Comment: Because he's using file I/O (in the form of [output redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)).